# NestJS TypeORM createQueryBuilder SELECT query

Tags: javascript, mysql, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I am trying to run a query

```
SELECT USER_CODE  
FROM USERS
```

using TypeORM in nestJS.

My database is MySQL and this database has a `users` table with the columns:

```
'USER_CODE', 'USER_EMAIL', 'USER_PASSWORD', 'USER_PHONE'
```

I've seen TypeORM official documents several times, but I don't understand them well.

```
//service.ts
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Users } from './entity/users.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { UsersSignupDto } from './dto/users.signup.dto';
import { generateCode } from 'src/common/utils/code.generator';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Users) private userRepository: Repository<Users>,
  ) {}

  async signup(body: UsersSignupDto) {
    const user = await this.userRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select('users.user_code')
      .from(users,'users')
      .where('users.user_code = :id', { id: '74EQQK' })
      .getOne();
    console.log(user);
   
}
```

the code returns 'null' but I checked that table's rows are not empty.

but when i tried

```
const user = await this.userRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .where('users.user_code = :id', { id: '74EQQK' })
      .getOne();
      console.log(user);
```

It works.. but this query gets all information from the table.

I just want to get 'user_code' column.

How to make this work? Can someone link me the references information?

Comment: It's not nestjs related, it's typeorm related. Take a look in documentation https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#getting-values-using-querybuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using queryBuilder observe the distinction between *entities* and *raw SQL data*, and use the appropriate API methods.

getOne (and getMany) will not work when your query returns raw SQL data rather than ORM entities. Use .getRawOne (or getRawMany) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but I dont have rep, but I think you confused the dataSource method with the get repository method.

```
const user = await this.dataSource
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .select("foo.user_code")
    .from(User, "foo")
    .where("foo.id = :id", { id: '74EQQK' })
    .getOne()
```

should work fine if you have `dataSource` setup properly in `app.module.ts`, then make sure it is injected, which means adding it to `constructor` of this `Service`,

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Users) private userRepository: Repository<Users>,
    private readonly dataSource: DataSource
  ) {}
//.......
}
```

more on that [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#typeorm-integration)